static constexpr definitions in a class vs in main function
When I try to define some variable in main-function I can define the variable as:
int main () 
{
    constexpr unsigned int  VariableName = 10;
}

However when I try to encapsulate the variables in a class it does not allow me to write it as:
class myClass
{
public:
    constexpr unsigned int  VariableName = 10;
};

but it does allow me to write it as a static member of the class:
class myClass
{
public:
    static constexpr unsigned int  VariableName = 10;
};

Why can I not define a variable in a class just as constexp dataType VariableName ? Why should I always use static in this case ?
My initial goal was to store some parameters for a signal model  in a class so that I could keep track of what did I change and to see the effect of those parameters on the signal model. Because of that I wanted to use constexpr and a class that encapsulates those parameters.

Because if the field is constexpr, it doesn't make sense to store it in every instance

its rare that c++ helps you to avoid nonsensical constructs. This is one of such cases

Dupe: Why can't non-static data members be constexpr

Suppose this would be allowed
class myClass
{
public:
    constexpr unsigned int  VariableName = 10;
};

Then, because it is constexpr and initialized with 10, there is no way it can have a different value for different objects. The language helps you by forcing you to make explicit what is the case anyhow: it's the same value for all instances. If you want it to have different values in different objects you cannot make it constexpr. Hence, there is no disadvantage but advantage in explicitly declaring it static.

My initial goal was to store some parameters for a signal model  in a class so that I could keep track of what did I change and to see the effect of those parameters on the signal model. Because of that I wanted to use constexpr and a class that encapsulates those parameters.

@BBB ok, so you can also make it static, no?

Actually yes I just wanted to know why and I think I get it from the post that has been shared. But how else can I encapsulate some parameters if we don't need to use classes for that ? Any suggestions ?

@BBB sorry I dont understand the problem. Why can you not make it static ?

I dont know I always get the following error if it is not static. However it is not a problem for me if it is static so changed it.
error: non-static data member ‘M’ declared ‘constexpr’

@BBB from your last comment it is not clear: do you still get an error when it is static ? Assuming the answer is "no" - just keep it static. This is the correct way to use a constexpr field.

@wohlstad
if I write "static" I don't get an error.
